# Find unordered words with RegEx

Tags: python, regex

I want to use RegEx to find the first sequence within a string where a set of words appears, by any order.

For example, if looking for the words `hello`, `my` and `world`, then:

- for `hello my sweet world` the expression would match `hello my sweet world`;
- for `oh my, hello world` it would match `my, hello world`;
- for `oh my world, hello world` it would match `my world, hello`;
- for `hello world` there would be no match.

After some research, I tried the expression `(?=.*?\bhello\b)(?=.*?\bmy\b)(?=.*?\bworld\b).*`, which does not solve my problem, as it matches the whole string if all words are present, as in:

- for `oh my world, hello world` it matches `oh my world, hello world`

What would be the apropriate expression to achieve what I described?

(Although RegEx is the preferred method for my program, if you think is not the way to go, any other python solution is welcome.)

Comment: Why would you want a regex to solve this task?

Comment: @YassinHajaj other suggestions are welcome, although it would be easier to fit a regex cleanly in the program im working on, as i already use regex for other search tasks in the same method

Comment: @CertainPerformance python, will edit

Comment: If repeating patterns are not allowed then try [this](https://regex101.com/r/s7dk7y/1). What you need is in first capturing group of each successful match.

Comment: You could do [this too](https://regex101.com/r/s7dk7y/2) with `regex` module if it supports references to relative captured groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this task best gets done with some programming logic and regex wouldn't be easy and efficient. But here is a regex that seems to be doing your job and doesn't matter whether you have repeating words (hello my world) present or not,

```
\b(hello|my|world)\b.*?((?!\1)\b(?:hello|my|world)\b).*?(?:(?!\1)(?!\2)\b(?:hello|my|world)\b)
```

The idea here is,

1. Make an alternation group `\b(hello|my|world)\b` and put it in group1
2. Then optionally it can have zero or more any characters following it.
3. Then it must be followed by any of the remaining two words and not the one that got matched in first group which is why I have used `((?!\1)\b(?:hello|my|world)\b)` and this second match is then put in group 2.
4. Then again it can have optionally zero or more any characters following it.
5. Then again we apply the same logic where the third word should be the one that wasn't captured in either group1 or group2, hence this regex `(?:(?!\1)(?!\2)\b(?:hello|my|world)\b)`

**[Here is a Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZvFhmr/1)**

Comment: this seems perfect! will check it as correct after some testing. thank you very much.

Comment: thought you might find this interesting: i made a program that generates that expression with variable words for my project here: https://pyfiddle.io/fiddle/03bfbfa3-53f3-437a-a7dc-ce9630e3a46d/?i=true

Comment: @JocaPinto: That's pretty good. Yes the regex is pretty systematic and logical which enables one to generate it through code and you did it :)

Answer (score 2):

Unified iterative *pythonic* approach by using [Pattern.finditer()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Pattern.finditer) function and [Set](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#set) object:

```
import re

test_str = '''The introduction here for our novel. 
Oh, hello my friend. This world is full of beauty and mystery, let's say hello to universe ...'''

words_set = {'my', 'hello', 'world'}    # a set of search words
words_set_copy = set(words_set)
pat = re.compile(r'\b(my|hello|world)\b', re.I)
start_pos = None
first_sequence = ''

for m in pat.finditer(test_str):        
    if start_pos is None:
        start_pos = m.start()           # start position of the 1st match object
    words_set_copy.discard(m.group())   # discard found unique match 

    if not words_set_copy:              # all the search words found
        first_sequence += test_str[start_pos: m.end()]
        break

print(first_sequence)
```

The output:

```
hello my friend. This world
```

---

You may transform the above approach into a function to make it reusable.

Comment: this is super smart, nice one. would you mind explaining the re.I as the second argument in re.compile?

Comment: @Datanovice, welcome, `re.I` is shortcut for `re.IGNORECASE` option